# Saving Hashes into a Text Field and then querying on Hash in where clause

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to save the ruby hash in the database like
Metrics table has name,values fields.

```
metrics.create("Registered", '{"Gender": "Male", "Age": 21}')
```

I want the query should run like this.

```
select count(*) from metrics where name=“Registered” and values.age > 20
```

As per best of my knowledge it will not work. But Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the database used is postgresql, you can have a json column named values and then use json_extract_path_text(values, age) to extract 'age'

Reference for json_extract_path_text can be seen [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am using MySQL